# How to make the SyntaxConformanceTest use sensible values when it calls the create action of my new API?

Tags: api

I created a [patch for CiviCRM](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6059) that allows saved searches to be created using the API.

Now it turns out that this SavedSearch API [does not pass](https://test.civicrm.org/job/CiviCRM-Core-PR/3907/) certain syntax conformance unit tests.

One of the problem is that some of the tests try to create a new saved search, and they try to assign a string like `form_values_273form_values_576` to the `form_values` field of the saved search entity.

The saved search BAO expect `form_values` to be a serialized array, and because `form_values_273form_values_576` obviously is not, errors occur, causing some the unit tests to fail. (see e.g. line 239 of /CRM/Contact/BAO/SavedSearch.php)

Is there a way to make those unit tests use a sensible value for `form_value`? `NULL` should do as well, I guess.

Comment: I think this forum thread is related: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33990.0

Answer (score 1):

For most of the tests, it was sufficient to [provide an `assignTestValue` method](https://github.com/johanv/civicrm-core/commit/4f0a0e58134ce12ed22ce0261145ced0252d1323) in the SavedSearch BAO.

This did not solve the problem though for [testCreateSingleValueAlter](https://test.civicrm.org/job/CiviCRM-Core-PR/3923/testReport/junit/%28root%29/api_v3_SyntaxConformanceTest__testCreateSingleValueAlter/testCreateSingleValueAlter_with_data_set__46/).